# Timelike Directions

Tags: general-relativity, time, causality

I'm trying to understand timelike directions.

$$\gamma[e_0+\beta(\cos\theta e_1+\sin\theta e_2)]=k^\mu\partial_\mu$$

My questions:

1. is $\beta$ the velocity of the massive particle as described by its local reference frame?
2. is $\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}$?
3. is there some way of transforming the equation so that it's dealing with $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$ and I can ignore the initial $\frac{dt}{d\tau}$?

Comment: What is the source of your equation? Are the $e_i$ part of the angles, or are they some sort of unit vector? (If so, $e_1\cos\theta$ is a clearer notation.) Are you defining a differential operator? What is it supposed to be acting on?

Comment: You're asking other people to explain your own notation to you?